# how can i convert spark dataset into geomesa feature?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, geoserver, geomesa

I want to know what is the best way to display geojson mongo LineString using GeoMesa, I found that GeoMesa can read from the cassandra database, but my point is that my data is stored in mongoDb. therefore, I can see that GeoMesa can be integrated with the Apache search engine, which I already use apache-spark to import this data. My question is, does anyone try or know how a source of geodata can be a source of geomedia?

Answer (score 1):

GeoMesa doesn't currently support MongoDB. If you want to be able to make efficient spatial queries, then you would have to ingest your data into GeoMesa using one of the supported [storage options](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/current/user/getting_started.html#getting-started). If you just want to create GeoTools SimpleFeatures from your current RDD or dataframe, then you should be able to use a GeoTools [SimpleFeatureBuilder](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/feature/simple/SimpleFeatureBuilder.html).

Comment: how to convert spark dataset into geomesa feature ?